# GPIO button resets STM32

Tags: stm32, nrst

I'm using STM32L031 in TSOP20 package on custom board. User can control it with encoder, which contains also push button. Endoder push button is connected to pin 3 on package(PC15), which is right next to NRST on pin 4. There is  a 100n capacitor placed on NRST pin, 100n and 4u7 on VDD and 10n and 1u on VDDA. Board worked well for few days, but now, pressing encoder button causes restarts. PINRSTF flag in RCC_CSR register is set, so reset came from pin. All other functions I use (I2C display, PWM generation, ADC, encoder clocking timer) work well.

Power supply is stable, I haven't noticed any change when I pressed the button.
I checked, that pins aren't shorted. When I push the button, NRST is pulled to about 0.3V. I tried to measure resistance between NRST and button traces, but haven't got any meaningful values.

Is it possible, that pins are somehow shorted internally? I thought also about flux contamination or humidity, but I cleaned whole board with alcohol multiple times and it's placed on pretty dry place.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a pull-up on the reset pin? And about that capacitor, is it an SMD type? If so, it might be cracked, did you check that?

Comment: "I tried to measure resistance between NRST and button traces, but haven't got any meaningful values."  What did you see?  The NRST pin has an internal pull-up that's fairly weak (up to \$65\mathrm k\Omega\$ "equivalent resistance"), so it wouldn't take much leakage.  Experimenting with a stronger pull-up on that (i.e., \$10\mathrm k\Omega\$ or even \$5\mathrm k\Omega\$) might be helpful.

Comment: I don't have pull-up on reset pin. It isn't recommended here, so I didn't add any.
https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00112257-getting-started-with-stm32l0xx-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf
I desoldered capacitor and measured, looked to be ok.

Comment: When I measured resistance, I saw anything from 600 ohm to megaohms, depending on where I put positive probe. Board was without supply of course, but maybe some capacitors still had charge, I'm not sure.
I just tried adding 10k pull-up and reset didn't occured. 
Button and reset lines go parallel quite a long way, if that could be a factor.